# Canvas text recognition and comparison

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know that there are javascript OCR's such as Tesseract, but what I am trying to accomplish is have the user draw a certain letter or symbol that appears on the screen, and I need a way to check if that drawn image is equal to said symbol. The problem is there would be multiple symbols in an array and how would I make it only register first symbol every time.  EX: ToTXt, I want it to only check the t, than the o, than the T etc.

Comment: And how much may I ask, is the prize for guessing what your actual question is?

Comment: To identify individual letters you must isolate each character horizontally. You might use the simplifying assumption that a horizontal empty space indicates a letter-break. Then here is a previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084549/read-a-text-in-canvas-identify-a-location-of-text-in-canvas/37084953#37084953) outlining how you can identify a symbol versus a known set of symbols.

Comment: My bad enhzflep, let me try to clarify: I have a sequence, Ex:ToTOTooTttO How do I make check the first letter in the sequence and then remove it from the sequence every time. The sequence would be created using loop and array.